# Is there any way we can reduce size for all widgets including button, menu/menu item etc in Gnome 3.20 or above?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, desktop-environment

Recently I reduced the size of title bar in Fedora 24 Gnome 3.20 version. Basically I want to reduce size of every widget so that the space taken by application on screen will be reduce. Any help appreciated.